# Changing minDate option in JQuery DatePicker does nothing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have this jQuery datepicker code that initially set the minDate of the datepicker. After a user selects a starting date, I used the option attribute to change the minDate of the datepicker, but nothing happens. What did I do wrong and how should I make it work?

**Datepicker init code:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#starttime,#endtime,#validity').datepicker({
                numberOfMonths: [1, 2],
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                showAnim: 'slideDown',
                buttonImage: '../images/cal.gif',
                beforeShow: customRange,
                dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                firstDay: 1,
                changeFirstDay: false
    });
});
```

**Datepicker change minimum date code:**

```
var startdate = new Date(2010,4-1,
    4-1,0,0,0);

$("#endtime").datepicker('option','minDate',startdate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this should work. Did you check if there are any errors in your browsers error console. And when/how do you call the `$("#endtime").datepicker('option','minDate',startdate);` code?

Btw. is April, 3rd 2010 really the date you mean?

Check this for a working demo: http://jsbin.com/ecome (http://jsbin.com/ecome/edit for the code)

Comment: Check expanded answer. I made a demo where your exact code (minus the `buttonImage` and the `beforeShow` options) works exactly like expected. So your problem must lie somewhere else. Again I ask where/when/how do you call the `$("#endtime").datepicker('option','minDate',startdate);` code? As you still didn't answer that or provide more code

Comment: @gcb My example stopped working because I linked jQuery 1.4.2 with the files on jqueryui.com (which of course changed since March 2010) They are now at jQuery UI 1.8.16 which at least requires jQuery 1.5.1. I updated my example in the answer and made a new revison of yours with correct links http://jsbin.com/udufev/3

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the following:

```
$("#endtime").datepicker('option', {minDate:startdate});
```